# Quick regex help match same symbol

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get a regex to grab all the same symbols (repeated) in a row. Return 1 symbol or a chunk of all the same symbols. "=" or "==" but not "=" "=".

\W or \W+ do not work.

eg `"===--,,,--;[]'"`

```
array(
  [0] => ===
  [1] => --
  [2] => ,,,
  [3] => --
  [4] => ;
  [5] => [
  [6] => ]
  [7] => '
)
```

I do not need the code to get it into an array. I got that working. Just the regex portion to grab repeat symbols.

Comment: These symbols `;[]'"` don't repeat. Is repeating optional?

Comment: OP answer comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check for a repeat part in regex you need to use the [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Here is an example in javascript:

```js
a = "===--,,,--;[]'"
t = a.match(/(.)(\1*)/g)
console.log(t)
```

Here is a code in php:

```
preg_match_all("/(.)(\\1*)/", "===--,,,--;[]'", $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "==="
  [1]=>
  string(2) "--"
  [2]=>
  string(3) ",,,"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "--"
  [4]=>
  string(1) ";"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "["
  [6]=>
  string(1) "]"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "'"
}
```

If you want to specify **only** these specific chars you can use:

```
preg_match_all("/([=\-,;\[\]'])(\\1*)/", "===--,,,--;[]'", $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

Comment: That matches repeating and non-repeating characters and doesn't match specifically whatever OP describes as special.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the original input was only with the "special chars", so I assumed he had only them in the string. Answer updated with an option to match **only** these chars.

Comment: And I misread the answer and OP hasn't clarified "repeated".  Gives them what they asked for.  Be ready for mass comments to "do this and that" :)

Answer (score 0):

Match all symbols "repeating in row" (consecutive):

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/(.)(\\1)(\\1+)?/", "===--,,,--;[]'", $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "==="
  [1]=>
  string(2) "--"
  [2]=>
  string(3) ",,,"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "--"
}
```

You can test this code: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/wuFn3j)